# Forcing media queries to respect the resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm having a problem with the media queries, currently I'm using bootstrap and in one site I'm having this problem, I have the media queries with this sizes 360px, 640px and 768px.

There is a div that is not respecting the media queries, for instance I have a `margin-left:5%`; in the 360 media query, 3% in the 640 and -1% in the 768 and when I'm in the 360 media query is using the margin of the 768 the same with the 640.

I tried to put an !important in the 360 and 640 but is just taking the 640px margin. I resize to 768 and this margin keeps as it must be, so it looks like the 768 have more hierarchy.

There is a way to define the hierarchy of the media queries and to force them to respect the styles  of the media query that I need?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 640px){
    DIV#id{
        margin-left: 5%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 768px){
    DIV#id{
        margin-left: 3%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    DIV#id{
        margin-left: -1%;
    }
}
```

you have to always mention the min and max width. and always use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

in your html page